# "Owner" permissions for individual within Google drive Shared Drives

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, permissions, publish, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm attempting to publish a webapp from a google script that I have that is located within a shared drive in my organization.
However, when attempting to do this by pressing prompt>publish as webapp within the Google Apps Script editor, the prompt gets stuck on "Fetching data" indefinitely:

[image]

Upon looking into the network communication, you can see that the reason the prompt is hanging is because I am not the owner of the file:

[image]

Upon checking permissions to see whom is the owner, I see that everyone has "editor" access to the file, which makes sense as the file is located in a shared drive.

**Not one individual person is an owner, and thus I don't see a way to publish web apps from within shared drives.**

How might I accomplish this?

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

### Seems to be a bug

What you can do:

Star the [related issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/163586454) that has already been risen on Google's Public Issue Tracker to increase visibility. The more people show that they are affected, the more likely Google is going to react soon.